# Plotting a corrugated ribbon on a 3D Plot

Tags: plotting, vector-calculus

I was assigned to write the following code:

```
Clear[P, t]; 
P[t_] = {-t, t, (1/2) t (8 - t)}; 
arch = 
  ParametricPlot3D[P[t], {t, 0, 8}, 
    Axes -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, PlotRange -> All, 
    Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> CMView, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

The output from the code is:

[image]

I was then tasked with obtaining the unit tangent vectors, the unit normal and binormal vectors with the following code:

```
Clear[P, x, y, z, t, unittan, mainunitnormal, binormal]; 
P[t_] = {-t, t, (1/2) t (8 - t)};
curve = ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[P[t]], {t, 0, 8}]; 
unittan[t_] = P'[t]/Sqrt[P'[t] . P'[t]]; 
unittanvectors = Table[Vector[unittan[t], Tail -> P[t]], {t, 0, 8, 0.5}]; 
mainunitnormal[t_] = N[unittan'[t]/Sqrt[Expand[unittan'[t] . unittan'[t]]]]; 
mainnormalvectors = 
  Table[
    Vector[mainunitnormal[t], Tail -> P[t], VectorColor -> Red], 
    {t, 0, 8, 0.5}]; 
binormal[t_] = N[Cross[unittan[t], mainunitnormal[t]]]; 
binormalvectors = 
  Table[Vector[binormal[t], Tail -> P[t], VectorColor -> Red], {t, 0, 8, 0.5}]; 
everything = 
  Show[curve, unittanvectors, mainnormalvectors, binormalvectors, 
    ViewPoint -> CMView, PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

which produces the following plot with vectors:

[image]

I am now asked to plot a ribbon two units wide whose center curve coincides with the curve plotted above. Corrugate the ribbon if possible. The hint that was provided was to use `binormal[t]`.

One of the plots I produced was using the following code:

```
ParametricPlot3D[P[t] + s mainunitnormal[t] +  Cos[3 s] binormal[t], 
  {t, 0, 8}, {s, -Pi, Pi}, 
  PlotPoints -> {15, 15}, ViewPoint -> CMView, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image]

Is my plot in line with what assigned task demands? Also, how can I go about ensuring that the ribbon is only two units wide?

Comment: try the option `PlotTheme -> "ThickSurface"` in `ParametricPlot3D`?

Answer (score 5):

We can simplify the calculate by use `FrenetSerretSystem`, and we construct a parametric solid region.

$$ P(t)+ (0,s,\cos3s).(T(t),N(t),B(t))+(0,0,h).(T(t),N(t),B(t))$$

Here $$0 \leq t \leq 8, -\pi\leq s \leq \pi, -1\leq h\leq 1$$

`P[t] + ({0, s, Cos[3 s]} + {0, 0, h}).{unittanvectors[t],  mainunitnormal[t], binormal[t]}`

and then draw the boundary of region independently.

```
Clear["`*"];

P[t_] = {-t, t, (1/2) t (8 - t)};
curve = ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[P[t]], {t, 0, 8}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}];
{unittanvectors[t_], mainunitnormal[t_], binormal[t_]} = 
  Last@FrenetSerretSystem[P[t], t];
solid = P[t] + ({0, s, Cos[3 s]} + {0, 0, h}).{unittanvectors[t], 
     mainunitnormal[t], binormal[t]};
SetOptions[ParametricPlot3D, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 30, 
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ViewPoint -> {-2.37, -0.52, -2.35}];
i = ParametricPlot3D[solid /. {h -> 1}, {t, 0, 8}, {s, -Pi, Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> Cyan];
j = ParametricPlot3D[solid /. {h -> -1}, {t, 0, 8}, {s, -Pi, Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> Purple];
u = ParametricPlot3D[solid /. {t -> 0}, {s, -Pi, Pi}, {h, -1, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Yellow];
v = ParametricPlot3D[solid /. {t -> 8}, {s, -Pi, Pi}, {h, -1, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Yellow];
p = ParametricPlot3D[solid /. {s -> -Pi}, {t, 0, 8}, {h, -1, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Blue];
q = ParametricPlot3D[solid /. {s -> Pi}, {t, 0, 8}, {h, -1, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Blue];
Show[i, j, u, v, p, q]
```

[image]